# Контактная информация во вконтакте на Swift

Tags: swift, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте.

Пробую работать с API ВКонтакте, но из-за нехватки информации или какой-либо документации на Swift не особо это получается. Разобрался, как авторизовываться, но как работать со стандартными методами API, не понял. Покажите, пожалуйста, как получить хотя бы какую-либо информацию о пользователе. Пробовал получить информацию о том, установил ли пользователь приложение или нет, но не знаю, как прописать id пользователя:

```
VKApiUsers.isAppUser(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот держи, тут подробно все: http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1659&rub=37 сам использовал сей метод

Comment: Ну не знаю даже, мне просто сложно разобраться с документацией, не понимаю, как с методами работать, а там все не php, не облегчает задачи. Но спасибо!

Comment: На самом деле проще, чем кажется, там и исходники есть, единственная сложность иногда с такими авторизациями - это правильно создать приложение в соцсети, вот тут у меня так реализовано: http://onclickweb.kz/coment.php как раз по этой схеме